# How to iterate through cell content based ranges in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I want to automate some annoying work in excel and need some help.

I have a huge report which has 200k+ rows and about 500 columns and my task is to find out which cells of a column are never used.
This was fairly easy and I managed it to create a script that works for that so far.
But now I want to distinguish between row types and return for each row type whether there are columns that are never used.
My problem is that I do not know how to iterate through the contents of a cell, so that if the row type changes my script will count the empty columns for the next row type.

I hope you get the idea and can help me. You do not have to give me the full code but maybe an idea of how I can get to the solution :)

This is the vba code I currently have and that gives me the correct solution but without distinguishing between the rowtypes

```
Public row As Long
Public rowMax As Long
Public startRow As Integer
Public materialType As String
Public filter As String
Public col As Integer
Public colMax As Integer
Public isUsed As Boolean

Sub bestimmeObFelderGenutzt()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        filter = "I"
        startRow = 2
        rowMax = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
        colMax = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        materialType = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(filter & startRow).Value

        For col = 1 To colMax
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, col + 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, col).Value
        Next col

        For row = 2 To rowMax
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row).Value
                For col = 1 To colMax
                    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col)) = False Then
                        isUsed = True
                        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, col + 2).Value = 1
                    Else:
                        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, col + 2).Value = 0
                    End If
                Next col
        Next row
    End With
End Sub


Sub findeUngenutzteSpalten()
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        rowMax = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
        colMax = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Spaltenüberschrift"
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Jemals benutzt?"

        For col = 3 To colMax
            isUsed = False
            For row = 2 To rowMax
                If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(row, col).Value = 1 Then
                    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & col - 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, col).Value
                    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & col - 1).Value = "Ja"
                    GoTo WeiterCol
                Else:
                    If row = rowMax Then
                        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & col - 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, col).Value
                        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & col - 1).Value = "Nein"
                    Else:
                        GoTo WeiterRow
                    End If
                End If
WeiterRow:
            Next row
WeiterCol:
        Next col
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by `to iterate through the contents of a cell`? And not sure that I understand what is the `row types`. If you give brief examples of your worksheets - that can make things easier.

Comment: So I have certain materials and each material has its own type which is the row type. For each material type I want to find columns that are unused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your task correctly this should work, copy to your module and read comments:

```
Sub FindUnusedColumnsPerRow()
Dim cellRow As range, cellColumn As range
Dim rowRange As range, columnRange As range
Dim rowsCount As Long, columnsCount As Long
Dim insertRow As Long
Dim listOfEmptyColumns()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim arrayCheck As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' I assume that this is your sheet with materials where you want to find unused columns
        rowsCount = .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).row ' get last row
        columnsCount = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' get last column

        For Each cellRow In range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rowsCount, 1)) ' going through all rows - here I suppose that material type is in the 1-st column, 1-st row is a header and data starts from 2-d row

            For Each cellColumn In range(.Cells(cellRow.row, 2), .Cells(cellRow.row, columnsCount)) ' for each row looking through all columns - I suppose that data starts from 2-d column
                If cellColumn = "" Then ' if the cell is empty.
                    ReDim Preserve listOfEmptyColumns(i) ' expanding array when needed
                    listOfEmptyColumns(i) = cellColumn.Column ' adding column number to an array, you may change it to = .cells(1,cellColumn.Column) to put a header name instead of column number
                    i = i + 1 ' increment the counter
                End If
            Next

            On Error Resume Next ' a small trick to check whether the array with column numbers is empty
            arrayCheck = UBound(listOfEmptyColumns) ' if the array is empty - an #9 "Subscript out of range" exception will be thrown

            If Err.Number = 0 Then ' error number is 0 - means that there was no error
                With Sheets("Sheet2") ' I suppose this is the sheet to store results
                    insertRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1 ' find the row to insert
                    .Cells(insertRow, 1) = cellRow.Value ' put the type to 1-st column
                    j = 2 ' start filling the row of the type with numbers of empty columns

                    For i = 0 To UBound(listOfEmptyColumns) ' populating data from array
                        .Cells(insertRow, j) = listOfEmptyColumns(i)
                        j = j + 1
                    Next
                End With
            End If

            Err.Clear ' clearing the error, because it still holding an error information (if it was thrown)
            On Error GoTo 0 ' don't forget to switch on normal error handling

            Erase listOfEmptyColumns ' reset array before next row as the data is stored on sheet2
            i = 0 ' reset the counter for further use
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```